# What is the differences between real so file and ln -s

Tags: unix, shared-libraries

for example, my directory like this:

```
lib
|
+--foo.so
+--bar.so -> bar.so.1.0.0.0
+--bar.so.1.0.0.0
```

Are these both ways always same?

The reason I ask this question is that I found unix will copy to real so file when I

```
cp -r lib /path/to/
```

new directory like this:

```
/path/to/lib
|
+--foo.so
+--bar.so
+--bar.so.1.0.0.0
```

Comment: Do "cp -a lib /path/to/" solve the issue?

Comment: Although it is not immediately obvious from the title that it will be the case, I think you'll find some of the information for [Difference between version number, minor version and release](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15454516/15168) helpful; it is about version numbers on shared objects.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your useful extern knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `so` and `ls -s` is the difference between a file and a symbolic link. Symbolic links are like aliases to other files and operations on them result in changes in the linked files. When you do `cp`, it copies the linked file to the target directory with the link name as the file name, i.e., it reads the linked file when it opens the symbolic link to copy it. So lose the link and instead get a copy of the linked file. If you use `-P` option of the `cp` command you can preserve the symbolic link information.

```
cp -P lib /path/to/
```